# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method IsUserInCc

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

**My Code:**

```
elections = elections.Where(e => e.Creator == Username || e.Approver == Username || IsUserInCc(e.Cc,Username))
    .OrderBy(e => e.Status)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Group);
var test = elections.FirstOrDefault();

private bool IsUserInCc(string cc, string username)
{
    var ccList = cc.Split(';');
    if (ccList.Contains(username))
        return true;
    return LDAPUtility.Instance.IsUserInGroup(ccList.ToList(), username);
}
```

**Error:**

LINQ to Entities does not recognize method IsUserInCc.

From many posts, I can understand why error was thrown. Basically IsUserInCc is not available in SQL execution. I need somehow convert it back to C# to handle it.

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize my method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662117/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-my-method)

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741642/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-in-query)

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228773/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostringint32)

However, in my specific case, what is the best approach?

Comment: Have you any Exception or something??

Comment: Visit last Answer please!

Comment: what is the purpose of LDAPUtility.Instance.IsUserInGroup(ccList.ToList(), username);? if that can be removed or reworked the query can probably be compatible with IQueryable

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to `list` first. Also note that `elections` must be able to hold a `list` for this to run.

```
elections = elections.ToList().Where(e => e.Creator == Username || e.Approver == Username || IsUserInCc(e.Cc,Username))
.OrderBy(e => e.Status)
.ThenByDescending(e => e.Group);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your function written in code, you cannot use that on `Queryables`. You need to convert to in-memory `list` and then apply the filter required using your function.

Comment: So what if `elections` contains a million records?

Comment: Then you need to convert whatever you are doing in this custom function to SQL function . No other go to handle this

Comment: But that's impossible because of the `string.Split`. I don't think there is any feasible way along the lines of "fetch first, then filter". OP should change the data structure, as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702878/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold but that would be a design change . But if i am not wrong , the one involved here is an email Id separator (;) text box string , which cannot be normalized anymore deeper.

Comment: Sure it can! The IDs shouldn't be stored as a semicolon-separated string.

Comment: @Gert `LDAPUtility.Instance.IsUserInGroup` looks to me a showstopper (if it is what the name implies). And since it's `Or`-ed with the `Contains` criteria, the whole criteria looks non translatable to SQL, with or w/o proper data normalization. So what the answerer suggests might be the only solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is that your underlying data isn't normalised properly. You need to put your CC's in a collection, not have them as a single deliniated string.

In SQL you'd need to add a new table called CC or something and put each user name in there and link it back to an election. Or if it's an in-memory collection, add a new property that in its Getter will do the split for you.

Either way, then you won't run into this kind of problem. If your data isn't properly structured, you will create problems for yourself further up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send `request` to `database`using `Linq` like:

```
var query = listData.Where(x=>x.Id == 123);
```

Type of this `query` is `IQueryable` that means your query not `Executed` yet!

Now you are sending data as `IQueryable` to method and can not process on your data, you have to `Execute` that with methods like: `Tolist()`, `ToListAsync()` or something like these.

The best way for these is that you get data from database without that method, after that you execute your query, you can Run this method.

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this :

```
 elections = elections.Where(e => e.Creator == Username || e.Approver == Username).Tolist().Where(e => IsUserInCc(e.Cc,Username))
.OrderBy(e => e.Status)
.ThenByDescending(e => e.Group);
```

var test = elections.FirstOrDefault();

```
private bool IsUserInCc(string cc, string username)
{
    var ccList = cc.Split(';');
    if (ccList.Contains(username))
        return true;
    return LDAPUtility.Instance.IsUserInGroup(ccList.ToList(), username);
}
```

Comment: This is different: it turns the last `||` into an `&&`.